# Bottles of beer

Tags: java

I have tried to make a version of bottles of beer on the wall, a basic for many people.

This is what I have but I do not understand why i am not getting any output whatsoever?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class PeopleInARoom
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int humanNum = 10;
        String word = "people";

        while (humanNum < 0) {

            if (humanNum == 1) {
                word = "person"; //singular, as in one person.
            }

            System.out.println(humanNum + " " + word + "people in a room");
            System.out.println("Wait...somebody left!");
            humanNum = humanNum - 1;

            if (humanNum > 0) {
                System.out.println(humanNum + " " + word + "people in a room");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hey, where has everybody gone?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int human = 10`, `while (humanNum < 0)`, just a little hint ;)

Comment: humanNum is declared as 10, however your while loop is not going to apply because it's more than 0. Your while loop will only execute when humanNum is less than 0.

Comment: while (humanNum > 0)

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, what happens?

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
int humanNum = 10;
```

and your condition is `while(humanNum < 0) {...}`. The `condition` is never satisfied so nothing happens.